# powershell network printer to text file

Tags: powershell-2.0

I have been researching and testing with powershell  2.0 and getting closer to a script that creates a text file containing connected network printers.  The desired text file will have the name of the computer as the name of the text file stored on a network location with the bellow format.

```
\\print server name\ name of printer
\\print server name \name of printer2
\\print server name\name of printer3
```

So far I have come up with the bellow powershell 2.0 script to name the text file according to the name of the PC.  However I am having problems getting the data of the txt file to create the data of the text file in the above format.

To create the file I am using the bellow powershell 2.0 code and get the bellow output file

```
$ComputerName = "$env:computername"
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Printer -ComputerName $ComputerName | Out-File \\printer server\printPCmap$\$ComputerName.txt   

Output:

Location      : 
Name          : \\print server name\printer
PrinterState  : 
PrinterStatus : 3
ShareName     : printer name
SystemName    : \\print server name
```

I then am able to get the newly created file by using the bellow script but unable to get it to rewrite the text file in the desired format.

```
Get-Content \\print server name\printPCmap$\$ComputerName.txt
```

And then by using `| Select-String "\\"` I can get the bellow data

```
Name          : \\print server name\name of printer
SystemName    : \\print server name
```

As you can see I am a bit far off from what I would like the 1 text file to look like at the end.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by calling for the printer information in a different table format and then using the Select-string command to call for the text I wanted.  I was then able to clean up the out file using Trim()